# Only half of my drawing using drawPolygon is showing up

Tags: java, drawing, awt, java-2d, graphics2d

This is the bit of code that does all of the drawing, but it's only drawing half of the arrow. When it's a vertical arrow (North or South), it cuts off the left side, and when it's horizontal (East or West) it cuts of the top, both centered right at the tip; becoming a perfect half an arrow.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setSize(100, steps * 50);
        for (int i = 1; i < steps + 1; i++) {
            y = i * 20;

            if (directions.peek() == "North") {
                int[] xNPoints = {x, x + 6, x + 2, x + 2, x + 2, x + 2, x + 6};
                int[] yNPoints = {y - 5,  y, y, y, y + 10, y, y};
                g.drawPolygon(xNPoints, yNPoints, 7);
            }
            else if (directions.peek() == "East") {
                int[] xEPoints = {x + 10, x + 5, x + 5, x - 5, x - 5, x + 5, x + 5};
                int[] yEPoints = {y, y + 6, y + 2, y + 2, y + 2, y + 2, y + 6};
                g.drawPolygon(xEPoints, yEPoints, 7);
            }
            else if (directions.peek() == "South") {
                int[] xSPoints = {x, x + 6, x + 2, x + 2, x + 2, x + 2, x + 6};
                int[] ySPoints = {y + 5, y, y, y - 10, y - 10, y, y};
                g.drawPolygon(xSPoints, ySPoints, 7);
            }
            else if (directions.peek() == "West") {
                int[] xWPoints = {x - 5, x, x, x + 10, x + 10, x, x};
                int[] yWPoints = {y, y + 6, y + 2, y + 2, y + 2, y + 2, y + 6};
                g.drawPolygon(xWPoints, yWPoints, 7);
            }
            g.drawString((String)directions.pop(), 5, y + 5);
```

The goal of the program is to return a set of user provided directions in reverse order, and I have a lot to clean up (add exceptions, clean up the GUI), but all of the code aside from what I just provided is used for prompting and storing the user's input for how many steps there are and what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the fact the you've overridden `paint` and also failed to call `super.paint` and move onto it `String` comparison in Java is not done with `==` but with `equals`, for example

```
if (directions.peek() == "North") {
```

Should be

```
if ("North".equals(directions.peek())) {
```

If you are overriding `paint` of a top level container (like `JFrame` or `JApplet`), you should avoid doing so.  Instead, you should create a custom component, like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, making sure that you also call `super.paintComponent`, otherwise you will end with some nasty paint artifacts

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details...

Comment: The string comparison was definitely an oversight. Thanks. I'm still learning the very basics of this GUI stuff, and our teacher didn't hardly go into it, so I think this resource should be helpful. Thank you. I couldn't find the duplicate post you said there was though. Could I get a link?

Comment: At the top of your question, there is now a link...

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking here. I realized I shouldn't have been using the == operator, and I've changed that now. The problem is still that only half the drawing is showing up, and there is an infinite loop of errors after paint starts.

Comment: In order to provide any other possible solutions, we're going to need to see a runnable example, this way we can run the code through a debugger